# How to modify a list of key values in dictionary based on matches of another dictionary keys in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as,

```
ex_dict={'recency': ['current',
  'savings',
  'fixed',
  'current',
  'savings',
  'fixed',
  'current',
  'fixed',
  'fixed',
  'fixed',
  'current',
  'fixed'],
 'frequency': ['freq',
  'freq',
  'freq',
  'freq',
  'freq',
  'freq',
  'infreq',
  'freq',
  'freq',
  'freq',
  'infreq',
  'freq'],
 'money': ['med',
  'high',
  'high',
  'med',
  'high',
  'high',
  'low',
  'high',
  'md',
  'high',
  'high',
  'high']}
```

another dictionary as,

```
cond_dict= {'recency': {'current': 0.33, 'fixed': 0.5},
           'frequency': {'freq': 0.83},
            'money': {'high': 0.67}}
```

Here i would like to fill in the list of values in ex_dict if it's element existed in the key of dictionary cond_dict.

for example:

In dictionary ex_dict, there is a key called 'recency', it has a list with 12 elements, here there are 3 unique elements in it such as (current,savings,fixed).

These three elements should be existed in the dictionary cond_dict keys, if any one of element not existed in this dict key its value should be added as 'RARE' in list associated with ex_dict.

Here is a sample output: savings from original list is replaced with RARE as savings not existed in the key of cond_dict.

```
'recency': ['current',
  'RARE',
  'fixed',
  'current',
  'RARE',
  'fixed',
  'current',
  'fixed',
  'fixed',
  'fixed',
  'current',
  'fixed']
```

Could you please write your suggestions/answers on it?.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for k,v in ex_dict.items():
    ex_dict[k] = [item if item in cond_dict[k] else 'RARE' for item in v]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
for key in cond_dict:
        for k in ex_dict:
            if k == key:
                for ke in cond_dict[k]:
                    if ex_dict[k]:
                        a = ex_dict[k]
                        a.append('RARE')
                        ex_dict.update({k:a})
print(ex_dict)
```

Comment: Yeah, it should also be OK, and  but the first solution is a pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

> Although there are already answers posted on this, I posted the same because I tried it. Hope this helps and counts.

```
for i, v in ex_dict.items():            # loop through ex_dict
    check_list = cond_dict[i].keys()    # create a check_list to verify the values later
    for p, k in enumerate(v):           # loop through the values of ex_dict
        if k not in check_list:         # match each value with check_list
            v[p] = 'RARE'               # replace the unmatched value

print(ex_dict)                          # print result
```

> If you want it in a more pythonic way, here is the solution :)

```
res = {i: [k if k in cond_dict[i].keys() else "RARE" for k in v] for i, v in ex_dict.items()}    
print (res)
```